# Change value of checkbox after ajax sucess

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

### Ajax Jquery

```
 $(".myonoffswitch").live("click",function(){
 var prod_id = $(this).attr('id');
 var status = $(this).attr('value');
 var tdid =$(this).parent().prev().attr('class');
 var td = $(this).parent().prev();

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/ads_status'; ?>",
         dataType: "json",
        data: {
            'prod_id': prod_id,
            'status' : status
        },
        success: function(msg)
        {
        var updated_status = msg[0].post_status;

            if(updated_status=="0" && tdid == prod_id){

                  $(".myonoffswitch").attr("value", updated_status);


            }
            if(updated_status=="1" && tdid == prod_id){

                $(".myonoffswitch").attr("value",updated_status);
            }
        }
    });

 });
```

### HTML

```
  <table><tr>
 <?php foreach($get_product as $products) { ?>
 <td class="<?php echo $products->id ?>" id="on-of">
            <input type="checkbox" class="myonoffswitch" id="<?php echo $products->id; ?>" value="<?php echo $products->post_status;?>">
 </td>
 <?php } ?>
</tr></table>
```

Hi, here i updated the value after checkbox clicked to either 0 or 1. If checkbox value is 0, it is updated to 1 in database and vice versa. I got the updated value from ajax sucessfully, when it tried to change the value of checkbox with updated value, it changes value to all the checkbox obtained from foreach loop. I want to change value to only specific checkbox with class .myonoffswitch on which it is clicked not to all checkbox. How can i do this. I used $(this) after ajax sucess in place of using .myonoffswitch but i did not changed the value. Please what would be the mistake. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the current "this" value to reference it later:

```
 $(".myonoffswitch").live("click", function () {
     var $this = $(this);
     var prod_id = $this.attr('id');
     var status = $this.attr('value');
     var tdid = $this.parent().prev().attr('class');
     var td = $this.parent().prev();

         type: "POST",
         url: "<?php echo base_url().'index.php/cms/ads_status'; ?>",
         dataType: "json",
         data: {
             'prod_id': prod_id,
                 'status': status
         },
         success: function (msg) {
             var updated_status = msg[0].post_status;
             if (updated_status == "0" && tdid == prod_id) {
                 $this.attr("value", updated_status);
             }
             if (updated_status == "1" && tdid == prod_id) {
                 $this.attr("value", updated_status);
             }
         }
     });
 });
```

I got into the habit of using `$` to prefix jQuery variables, so `$this` seems appropriate. It also avoids doing `$(this)` over and over.

Comment: i want to update the value of checkbox with updated_status. If value of checkbox was 1 then update checkbox value to 0 and vice versa. Not the status of checked and unchecked for checkbox.

Comment: You just needed to save the outer `this` into a variable, as the `ajax` `success` callback gets a new `this`.

Comment: This is what exactly what i wanted. I did not knew that $(this) would not be saved after ajax sucess. Thank you.